# Databricks aes_decrypt() not giving original text for string encrypted using aes_encrypt()

Tags: encryption, aes, databricks

I have some data that I need to encrypt and I'd like to use the aes_encrypt function built into Databricks.  However, I'm unable to successfully encrypt and then get back the original text using the aes_encrypt() and aes_decrypt() functions build into Databricks.

An example is given below.

What do I need to do to get back the original text?

**Query:**

```
select 
  'test' as original_text,
  aes_encrypt('test','foobarfoobarfoobarfoobar') as encrypted,
  aes_decrypt(aes_encrypt('test','foobarfoobarfoobarfoobar'), 'foobarfoobarfoobarfoobar') as decrypted
```

**Output:**

```
original_text   encrypted                                       decrypted
test            shj898e14ahsu3yNcuNiI+iaVy4ajc5NBnReC08GjIA=    dGVzdA==
```

Comment: decrypt function return binary type that needs to be casted to a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post was helpful:
https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/aes_decrypt.html

Which leads to this solution:

```
-- this works
select 
  'test' as original_text,
  base64(aes_encrypt('test','foobarfoobarfoobarfoobar')) as encrypted,
  cast(aes_decrypt(unbase64(base64(aes_encrypt('test','foobarfoobarfoobarfoobar'))), 'foobarfoobarfoobarfoobar') as string) as decrypted;
```